# One thread waiting for multiple thread events

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have one thread waiting for some event from various number of other thread, which depend on an event from this one thread to continue processing. How can I code to avoid busy looping?

More specifically, I have multiple threads that process their respective video frame and write it to a screen buffer (at different locations). After they are all finished, the one thread sends the buffer to draw then those threads wait for the draw call to finish and then proceed to their next frames.

This needs to be implemented in C++. C++ standard used is not limited.

EDIT: `std::condition_variable` doesn't seem to be the solution. Since it requires a mutex, and the number of threads (mutexes) is known at runtime, and I can't put mutexes in `std::vector`

The pseudocode of my program is like this:

```
drawThread:
    loop:
        for each processThread:
            wait for event
        draw()

processThread:
    loop:
        process()
        notify drawThread
        wait for draw to finish
```

EDIT: What I tried:

```cpp
std::vector<std::atomic_bool> ready_flags;
std::atomic_bool finished_drawing = false;
void drawThread()
{
    while(true)
    { 
        CHECK:
        for(auto& flag: ready_flags)
        {
            if(!flag)
                goto CHECK;
        }
        draw();
        finished_drawing = true;
    }
}
void ProcessThread(int id)
{
    while(true)
    {
        process();
        finished_drawing=false;
        ready_flags[id] = true;
        while(!finished_drawing)
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: std::condition_variable https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: You only need one mutex for a condition variable. There is no law that says that every thread must always use its own, exclusive mutex. Doing so, actually, defeats the purpose of mutexes, since they are explicitly designed to be accessible by multiple threads. That's what mutexes are all about, after all.

Comment: Mutexes guard data against concurrent access from any number of threads. That said, you picked the tools (number of threads, communication method) already and now you have problems. However, maybe you should rather describe the goals, see also "XY Problem".

Comment: You say you can't use a vector of mutexes. In fact, [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16465633/580083), just you need to avoid reallocation by proper `reserve`. Alternatively, if you don't know the number of threads/mutexes in advance, you can use `std::deque` or `std::list` of mutexes instead. The problem might be, that you cannot wait for multiple condition variables at once. But this problem is solvable, e.g., by introducing some (lock-free) queue of events accompanied by a single condition variable.

Comment: @DanielLangr Can you please elaborate according to my cases? Even just pseudocode is appreciated.

Comment: @szppeter Sorry, but can't, at least in my free time. But I can suggest reading some good material about threading in C++. For example, _C++ Concurrency in Action_ is quite a good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figuring out a working solution

```cpp
const int processThreadCount;
std::atomic<int> ready_count{};
std::shared_mutex drawing_mutex;
std::conditional_variable_any can_draw;
void drawThread()
{
    while(true)
    { 
        std::unique_lock lk{drawing_mutex};
        canDraw.wait(lk, [&]{return ready_count==processThreadCount;};
        draw();
        ready_count=0;
    }
}
void ProcessThread(int id)
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::shared_lock lk{drawing_mutex};
        process();
        ++ready_count;
        can_draw.notify_one();
    }
}
```